# Should I let Release Management handling changing connection strings or use ASP.NET's Debug/Release on Web.Config?

Tags: asp.net, tfs

We're using TFS 2015 on-premises. I'm responsible for a very old ASP.NET WebForms app. The person who wrote this (I've never met him) back in the day, used some very non-standard ways of storing connection strings. (Perhaps, when he wrote it, ASP.NET didn't support connection strings being in the Web.Config file.) Anyway, I'm concerned about future developers knowing where to find the .ini files he placed around the web server to store connection strings. Therefore, I'm working on replacing the way the web app currently stores and retrieves database connection strings to putting them into the Web.Config file.

The problem I'm asking about is where is the better place to have a means of switching between production and test databases? I know that TFS's Release Management can handling changing where to point connection strings because upon the environment used. I also know that Visual Studio has the concept of a .Debug and .Production folders for specifying where to point for test and production databases. I just don't know which is best practice; to use TFS's Release Management or VS's Web.Config's transform. I'm wondering if Release Management now replaces Web.Config's transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TFS's Release Management to replaces Web.Config's transform is more flexible, you can replace tokens easily by adding a task. If modify VS's Web.Config's transform, you have to check in the change every time.

The task that can replace tokens exists in lots extension, you can install any one of them. For example:

- [Colin's ALM Corner Build & Release Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=colinsalmcorner.colinsalmcorner-buildtasks)
- [Release Management Utility tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.utilitytasks)
- [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)
- [Tokenization Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TotalALM.totalalm-tokenization)